# InputField not editable when in Edit Mode

Tags: visualforce, customer-portal, inputfield

I am rendering a VF page in Customer Portal and hoping to use inputField. Issue is that the field is not showing as editable, this happens when rendered from the portal (as a portal user) and my in my force.com app, see code below.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardController="Contact">
    <apex:form >
    <h1>Hello, {!$User.FirstName}</h1>
        <apex:pageBlock title="PP Form" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Personal Details">
                <apex:inputfield value="{!contact.name}"/> 
                <apex:inputfield value="{!contact.name}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like a permissions issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant to or not but the title of your question implies the mode="edit" attribute on apex:pageBlock changes the functionality of inputFields within it. It does not. It only controls what styles are used when rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you referring to: `Customer Portal User Licenses` or `Service Cloud Portal User Licenses` depending on the user licenses, some users don't have have access to update contacts, make sure your using a license that has access to 'Contacts' here:  https://na3.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/users_understanding_license_types.htm

Comment: Thanks Jordan, I am referring to Customer Portal User Licenses. I double checked the link and it seems the license type I am using (Customer Portal Manager Custom license) allows for create, read and update. Not sure what the issue is, but I am gonna try add the VF page to the page layout and see how it behaves then.

Comment: Not positive that `Contact` has a 'Name' record, but maybe try: `{!Contact.FirstName}` & `{!Contact.LastName}`

Comment: You are a legend Jordan - Thanks that did the trick. As the say in the UK, SchoolBoy Error

Answer (score 8):

Name is a read-only field that's basically FirstName and LastName concatenated. Try this with either of those fields, and make sure that the profile has Field Level access to those fields.

Comment: This is correct.  Name is definitely not editable as it is just a concatenation of FirstName + ' ' + LastName.